# Multiple angularness controllers in a view and how to load only when necessary

Tags: angularjs

I've got only one app controller by now, which keeps on getting larger and larger as the development goes on.

The app is offline and the controller contains static data structures with lot of informations.

Not all the pages make use of all the data contained in the controller, so I'd like to make the controller lighter.

Q1) To make the controller lighter, I'd like to know what solutions I might chose for that?

Q2) My guess is to create a second controller specifically for the page layout that would hold most of the related data and make use on the main controller to get the few data I need from it. But I have no idea how to do that.

Below is what I would want where stagesDescription is in the second controller (app.controller.stages.js.html) while stage.id is in the master controller:

```
<script src="js/app.controller.stages.js.html"/>

<div ng-repeat="photo in stagesDescription[stage.id].photos" 
    style="background-image: url(rsc/stage/{{stage.id}}/{{photo.file}}.thumb.jpg)"
    >
    <div>{{photo.description}}</div>
</div>
```

Note: I need to only load my controller when the view is loaded in order to avoid being in RAM all the time.

Comment: You should use a service for that. You can put all your data into one service and then create 2 controllers that will comunicate via service.

Comment: How would the second controller look like? And how would it be used in my html code snippet?

Comment: Btw, I'm sure if it's clear from my question, but I need to only load my controller when the view is loaded in order to avoid being in RAM all the time @jcubic

Comment: Use differnt controller for whatever you use in a view (if you use router you should have controller with a template and that's a view). Use main controller for whatever is common to both outside and inside a view and service to share data between.