# How to define a data with accent with ng-init?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I need to define a local model using ng-init. Unfortunately, I've got an error on the accent.
Any idea?

```
<div ng-init="
    descriptions = {
        floraison: { 
            photos: [
                {file:'1-PaniculeSansPollen',                       description:'Panicule sans pollen'},
                {file:'2-DebutEmissionPollenSurLeBrinPrincipal',    description:'Début émission pollen sur le brin principal'},
                etc. (remaining part of the code has been removed for the question)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 430-430 [é] in expression [descriptions = {
        floraison: { 
            photos: [
                {file:'1-PaniculeSansPollen',                       description:'Panicule sans pollen'},
                {file:'2-DebutEmissionPollenSurLeBrinPrincipal',    description:'Début émission pollen sur le brin principal'},
```

[edit] Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/bS6ZU/

Comment: Why aren't you initializing this variable in a controller ? In most of the cases, it's a [bad practise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to use ng-init for that !

Comment: Because I am exploring a way to keep my controller lighter than is gonna be at the end of the development. See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577464/multiple-angularness-controllers-in-a-view-and-how-to-load-only-when-necessary @Julien

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just missed few brackets

```
ng-init=" descriptions = {
        floraison: { 
            photos: [
                       {file:'1-PaniculeSansPollen',  description:'Panicule sans pollen'},
                       {file:'2-DebutEmissionPollenSurLeBrinPrincipal', description:'Début émission pollen sur le brin principal'}
                    ]
                   }
                }"
```

Comment: In my actual code, everything is well balanced, it was just an excerpt for the question. The error still is there @sylwester

Comment: please see there http://jsbin.com/vimero/4/edit in your jsfiddle probably again you missed something

Comment: Thanks but I cannot spot what was the problem. I see you transform some tag endings by doubling the slash (what does this mean?), but not all @sylwester

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Sorry for delay I wasn't sure about closing tags but they are fine you don't have do 'double close tags'. I don't remember where exactly but in one place was double quotation mark and coma on the end of you object and that makes your object invalid. I hope that will help. if that resolve your problem I'm rally appreciate if you can accept answer. Regards Sylwester